# file.getName() returns nothing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to get the name of a CSV file selected for the user, but the `getName()` method does not return any value.

This is the code

```java
private void readCSV(Uri uri) {
    InputStream is;
    File file = null;

    try {
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
            file = new File(uri.toString());
            Log.i("File selected: ", file.getName()); //file.getName() doesn't work 
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Why does this not return the name of the file?

**Edit 1**

```java
    private void readCSV(Uri uri) {
        InputStream is;
        File file;

        try {
                 /*This conditional is false*/
            if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
                file = new File(uri.toString());
                Log.i("File selected: ", file.getName()); //file.getName() doesn't
                is = new FileInputStream(file);
            } else {
               /* this part is the one that runs */

               is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
               Log.i("File selected: ", uri.getLastPathSegment()); //i tried this, it returns me 5049 but it is not the name of the selected file
            }
```

Comment: what is value of `uri.toString()` ?

Comment: ideally if the path you have given does not contain any name then a null string is returned. Are you sure there's a file name?

Comment: uri.toString() contains a path of the CSV file. And yes, the path contains a file name.

Comment: Why are you doing this `uri.getScheme().equals("file")`?

Comment: It is part of a solution to another problem: [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317824/como-puedo-leer-el-contenido-de-un-archivo-csv-guardado-el-dispositivo)
Precisely that conditional is false, its result is "content"

Answer (score 2):

`uri.toString()`  will return the object reference but not the file path.

You should call `uri.getPath()`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
new File(uri.getPath());
```

instead of

```
new File(uri.toString());
```

**NOTE:** `uri.toString()` returns a String in the format: `"file:///mnt/sdcard/image.jpg"`, whereas `uri.getPath()` returns a String in the format: `"/mnt/sdcard/image.jpg"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as ```file.getName()```

Answer (score 0):

> Getting file names through the apachecommons io lib https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html

```
String name = FileNameUtils.getName(uri.getPath());
```